# Idiomatic migration from Java to Kotlin of class that accesses inner class private members

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a Java class (`Outer`) that uses an inner builder class (`Outer.Builder`), accessing the private variables as part of the construction, as below:

```java
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Outer {
  private int mValue;

  private Outer(Builder builder) {
    mValue = builder.mValue;
  }

  public void printValue(PrintStream stream) {
    stream.println(mValue);
  }

  public static class Builder {
    private int mValue;

    public Builder setValue(int value) {
      mValue = value;
      return this;
    }

    public Outer build() {
      return new Outer(this);
    }
  }
}
```

used as follows:

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var builder = new Outer.Builder();
    var outer = builder.setValue(42).build();
    outer.printValue(System.out);
  }
}
```

I've attempted to take advantage of Android Studio's ability to migration Java code to Kotlin, which has given me the following result:

```kotlin
import java.io.PrintStream

class Outer private constructor(builder: Builder) {
  private val mValue: Int

  fun printValue(stream: PrintStream) {
    stream.println(mValue)
  }

  class Builder {
    private var mValue = 0

    fun setValue(value: Int): Builder {
      mValue = value
      return this
    }

    fun build(): Outer {
      return Outer(this)
    }
  }

  init {
    mValue = builder.mValue
  }
}
```

However, compilation fails, with:

```
Outer.kt:24:22: error: cannot access 'mValue': it is private in 'Builder'
    mValue = builder.mValue
                     ^
```

because (as the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/visibility-modifiers.html#classes-and-interfaces) states):

> In Kotlin, outer class does not see private members of its inner classes.

which this code runs afoul of in the `init` block, with:

```kotlin
mValue = builder.mValue
```

I'm aware that I can refactor this to not attempt this access (changing the `Outer` constructor such that it takes all the members, adding accessors to `Outer.Builder` for the necessary fields, etc), but I'd like to know whether there is an idiomatic Kotlin way to achieve this kind of builder pattern (with minimal modification to the initial Java class, if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin has [named arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#named-arguments), so the whole Builder pattern is embedded into the language:

```kotlin
class Outer(private val mValue: Int = 0) {
    fun printValue(stream: PrintStream) = stream.println(mValue)
}

//Usage:
fun main() {
    val outer = Outer(mValue = 42)
    outer.printValue(System.out)
}
```

However, this approach works nicely only for usage from Kotlin. For usage from Java, constructor should become private and traditional nested Builder should be declared:

```kotlin
class Outer private constructor(val mValue: Int) {
    class Builder {
        @set:JvmSynthetic // Hide 'void' setter from Java
        var mValue: Int = 0

        fun setValue(value: Int) = apply { this.mValue = value }

        fun build() = Outer(mValue)
    }

    fun printValue(stream: PrintStream) = stream.println(mValue)
}
```

To preserve convenient creation of `Outer` from Kotlin, we need to declare an auxilary top-level function whose name is the same as a type which we can use to replicate the constructor:

```kotlin
@JvmSynthetic // Hide from Java callers who should use Builder.
fun Outer(initializer: Outer.Builder.() -> Unit): Outer {
    return Outer.Builder().apply(initializer).build()
}
```

Usage from Java:

```java
public class BuilderUsage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer outer = new Outer.Builder().setValue(42).build();
        outer.printValue(System.out);
    }
}
```

Usage from Kotlin:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val outer = Outer { mValue = 42 }
    outer.printValue(System.out)
}
```

Comment: Very concise, particularly with the named keywords to the constructor. It's all been very helpful; for the moment I've decided to add accessors to the builder (`getValue()`), to avoid needing to use `@JvmSynthetic`, but it's great to see what's possible as the Kotlin usage becomes the more common.